# MIPS jump does not add 4 to PC

Tags: mips, mips32

I'm trying to understand the range of each branch instruction.

The `beq` and `bne` instruction do something like that :

PCnew = (PCold + 4) + (steps from branch point)*4

However the jump instruction does not add 4 to the PCold, although i know that every mips instruction add 4 (to go to next instruction). So if i write :

```
j loop
```

Then the PCnew takes the address of loop*4 and does not add four to it.Why is that? Am i getting something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumps use *absolute* addresses, while branches use *PC-relative* addresses.

So a jump just sets the PC to the jump destination address.

For a branch though, the branch *displacement* (aka *offset*) is added to the PC. However the PC has already been advanced to the next instruction at this point, so the branch destination address is: `<address of branch instruction> + 4 + <relative displacement>`.

Comment: But how can jump use absolute addresses ? Isn't mips's hardware build to add 4 to every instruction ?

Comment: Those are two unrelated concepts. The "adding of 4" is just what the Program Counter does by default (i.e. advances to the next 32 bit instruction). When a jump is encountered though, the PC is *replaced* by the absolute jump address (unlike a *branch*, where the PC is modified by the branch displacement).

Comment: So the PC keeps the 4MS bits and replaces the 28LS bits with the absolute just address ?

Comment: Not quite - the 28 bits are shifted left by 2 bits (multiplied by 4 in effect), since all PC addresses must be multiples of 4. This then gives you the full 32 bit address range with only 28 bits.

Comment: You're welcome - I can remember being initially baffled by microprocessors many years ago, as a teenager. ;-)